# Reformat Pandas Multiindex

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to convert a Pandas multi-index to a table.  I have tried stacking, unstacking, and cross-sections, but nothing seems to give quite the right output.

The multi-index table looks like this:

[image]

I would like to convert it to a format like this:

```
yearmo  cohort_string                       sum      count
2018-01 Bonds                               76418    17.0
2018-01 Bonds+Car Loan                      18538.0  17.0
2018-01 Bonds+Car Loan+Checking+Credit Card 48248.0  3.0
...
```

I know I could loop over the object and pull apart the pieces but there has to be a simpler way.  I have spent more time on this than I care to admit, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking for [`pd.DataFrame.reset_index()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html)?

Comment: That's what I was looking for.  This is definitely a duplicate question.  Thanks.